# Change Apache2 root folder drive

Tags: hard-drive, apache2, drive

I'm trying to change the directory of my default Apache site to a folder in another drive.

The problem arises with the fact the Ubuntu has named all my additional mounted drives as New Volume, New Volume1, New Volume2, etc.

The `space` in the drive name causes issues in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` which looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /media/omk/New Volume2/Server
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /media/omk/New Volume2/Server/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

On apache2 restart, I get the following error

```
Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
```

DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

This is caused due to the space in the path, which Apache assumes as 2 different arguments separated by a space.

I need to either make it look like a single argument retaining the path

OR

Change the volume name (which again I'm not able to figure out how)

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your DocumentRoot in quotes

`DocumentRoot "/media/omk/New Volume2/Server"`

Same goes for the directory directive.

`<Directory "/media/omk/New Volume2/Server/">`

To change the Volume name you can just remount the drive.

`sudo umount /media/omk/New\ Volume2` note: a slash will work to escape the space

`sudo mkdir /media/omk/volume2`

`sudo mount /dev/sdXX /media/omk/volume2` replace XX with the drive letter&number